# Group rows based on flag, with a single row as output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below in oracle 10g.

```
**Pat_no   pat_id   doc    doc_flag**
A1         123      ABD     Y
A1         123      ABC     Y
A1         123      ABE     Y
A1         123      ABF     Y
```

I want a single row output when all the different docs have the flag 'Y'.

```
**Pat_no    pat_id  doc_flag**
A1          123     Y
```

If any one has a doc_flag as 'N' then the output should be 'N'.

```
**Pat_no    pat_id  doc_flag**
A1          123     N
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
select pat_no, pat_id, min(doc_flag) doc_flag
  from t
 group by pat_no, pat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
select pat_no, pat_id, 'Y'
from t
group by pat_no, pat_id
having min(doc_flag) = max(doc_flag) and min(doc_flag) = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNT` aggregation function with `CASE`:

```
SELECT pat_no,
       pat_id,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT( CASE doc_flag WHEN 'N' THEN 1 END ) > 0
         THEN 'N'
         ELSE 'Y'
       END AS doc_flag
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY
       pat_no,
       pat_id
```